# How does Salesforce "external services" manage CORS?

Tags: lightning-web-components, cors, external-services

I start by testing calling a REST API from Postman : this works.
I then set up a Salesforce "External Service" and call the same service from a Flow : this works.
Then I create a LWC component which does the same thing with a fetch callout : this does not work, complaining about a CORS problem.

How does Salesforce External Services manage CORS ?
Why does calling the same REST API from Salesforce External Service and Salesforce LWC fetch not react identically regarding CORS ?

Comment: ...because CORS is only an issue for JS-based clients running in a container (e.g. a browser). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: So because LWC is running on the client (browser) and External Services on the server ?  Good point.